# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __declspec(dllimport)

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors

I have written a simple dll using cmake. The dll will be used in a visual studio application. Here are the files:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

hello::hello()
{
    std::cout << "constructor called";
}
```

**test.h (used to build dll)**

```
#pragma once

class __declspec(dllexport) hello
{
public:
    hello();
};
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(Test)

add_library(Test SHARED test.cpp)

include_directories($(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR))

install(TARGETS Test
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Test.pc
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/pkgconfig)
```

**test.h (included by application)**

```
#pragma once

class __declspec(dllimport) hello
{
public:
    hello();
};
```

After including the .lib file and trying to use the class Test, I an getting an LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __declspec(dllimport) and an LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals error.

How do I fix this?

**Edit:**

Exact error message:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall hello::hello(void)" (__imp_??0hello@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  test_proj   C:\(path to file)
```

**Edit 2**

I've solved my problem. I just had to set my project configuration and properties to x64. Thanks everyone who tried to help!

**Edit 3**

I tried linking a larger library that I made, but I got the same error. I also got the same error when I tried to replicate the above code example as well, so I'm not sure how it originally worked.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? I haven't been able to find anyone online with the same issue.

Comment: Please, add the **exact error message** to the question post. After the words `unresolved external symbol __declspec(dllimport)` should come the name of the symbol.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in CMake but the problem is that your program that's using the DLL needs to link with the .lib file that was generated when the DLL was built.

Comment: @Rup the cmake file generates a .lib file and a .dll file, and i am sure that i have linked with the lib file. that's why i don't know why this error is occurring.

Comment: ***and i am sure that i have linked with the lib file.*** The error message disagrees with this. Perhaps you did not link each configuration.

Comment: You really should be using a macro that is set to `__declspec(dllexport)` when building the dll and `__declspec(dllimport)` when using the dll instead if 2 separate headers for the same class.

Comment: @drescherjm I do use a macro in my actual library. This is just a test case I created to test why my linking wasn't working.

Comment: @drescherjm Also, I have linked both my header file and .lib file. If I don't, the compiler gives a different error. Is there anything else I have to link?

Comment: ***Is there anything else I have to link?*** No. Are you sure that you are linking a separate lib for debug and release and not mixing 32 and 64 bit? I have created probably 100 dlls in Visual Studio using CMake.

Comment: What do you mean different lib for debug and release? I have tried both 32 bit configuration 64 bit configuration, so I can rule out that possibility.

Comment: What I mean is you link a debug created import lib in debug mode and a release created import lib in release mode. Don't mix these or try to use the same .lib for both configurations. In my CMake setup I have these named differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215467/discussion-between-pranavagande-and-drescherjm).